# Android access views from another process

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is use a joystick to interact with my device(emulate tab or jump focus), I want to be able to access the contents of whatever activity is currently active (not my app screens).Root access is not a problem. What is the best approach to this? I can't seem to find many information online
Please point me in the right directions and I'll update this post with relevant information for future references

Comment: That is not generally possible, except perhaps on rooted devices or via a custom ROM.

Comment: If you attach a physical keyboard is it possible to achieve the tab movement?

Comment: yes but in a very chaotic order, android apps aren't generally optimized for that. Devs rarely use nextFocus* properties of views

Answer (score 0):

This is **not universally possible** due to security reasons and how Android processes are structured.

One way to implement this would be to have a **common Intent-driven interface** with the developers of the app, allowing you to send Intents to their app to trigger specific actions.

Apart from that, it would probably require a custom ROM which would allow such interaction between processes.

Comment: I vaguely remember some app that opened a settings page and navigated me to some certain setting through tap emulation a while ago. can't exactly tell what app it was